Hateoas RepresentationModelAssembler removes *some* values not annotated with @JsonIgnore from reponse
I'm trying a GET request that uses hateoas RepresentationModelAssembler in Spring Boot project with this method:
    @GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public EntityModel<Post> one(@PathVariable Long postId) {
        Post post = postRepository.findById(postId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomExceptionHandling.ResourceNotFoundException("Post", "ID", postId));
        return assembler.toModel(post);
    }


and this is my assembler
    @Component
    public static class PostModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Post, EntityModel<Post>> {
        @Override
        public @NonNull EntityModel<Post> toModel(@NonNull Post post) {
            return EntityModel.of(post,
                    linkTo(methodOn(PostController.class).one(post.getId())).withSelfRel()
            );
        }
    }


this is Post.java:
@Entity(name = "post")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Builder.Default
    private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    private String caption;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

Received Response:
{
"createdAt": "2023-01-01T12:00:00",
"caption": "Caption 1",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/posts/1"
}
}
}
Expected Response:
a similar one that includes user and id.
NOTE: I tried using @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS and Include.NOT_NULL), @JsonProperty, @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}), removed lombok and added public getters and setters, made id fields public, but nothing worked
EXTRA NOTE: when I added @JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
it produced the error: "Type definition error: [simple type, class com.example.demo.model.Post]" and somewhere below it: "Invalid Object Id definition for com.example.demo.model.Post: cannot find property with name 'id' (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel["content"])"

This can be lazy loading issue from hibernate side, try writing query with join using SQL or JPQL

still not sure what caused the issue, but managed to go around it by creating DTOs for all the model classes
